# Написать запрос SQL по базе Northwind (решить задачу с помощью подзапроса без JOIN)

Tags: sql, sql-server

В какие месяцы 1997 было больше всего продаж?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что от нас требуется именно месяца, в которых было больше всего заказов (таблица `Orders`), а не заказы, в которых было больше всего продуктов (таблица `order details`, столбец `quantity`). Если требовались месяца с количеством наибольших заказов, то решение такое

```
select month(orderdate) AS месяцы, count(*) as Заказы
from Orders
where YEAR(OrderDate) = 1997 
group by month(orderdate) 
order by Заказы DESC
```

Но каким бы было решение, если от нас требовалось вывести месяца с наибольшим количеством продуктов в заказах?

Comment: *Правильно ли я понимаю, что* Вопрос - только и исключительно к тому, кто дал тебе эту задачу. Никому не известно, что у него в голове.

Comment: но все же если правильно, то каким было бы решение уже другой задачи?) Задать вопрос лектору я к сожалению не имею возможности